# Xamarin Forms Custom Timpepicker, Focus() not working

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I implemented following solution [stack answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30187742/xamarin-forms-timepicker-24hour) to create a 24H timepicker in Xamarin, the problem with this solution is that the Focus() method to trigger the picker does not function on Android. If I remove the custom renderer, the Focus() works again on Android.

Answer (score 0):

i have write custom renderer and set action to 
element.ShowPicker =()=>Control.PerformClick();