# Xamarin Forms: Timepicker 24hour and custom interval on Android

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, custom-renderer

I can't seem to get this right. There are some old post on this subject but non of them offer a working solution. This is what I'm trying to get done:

-Timepicker in 24hour format instead of am/pm
-Custom interval, for example 15 minute or 20 minute interval in the picker
-The custom picker must be able to show when Focus() is set in code

works easily in iOS but can't get the Android customrenderer to work :(

Anyone any ideas?

I tried all the ideas that can't be found but non of those seem to work properly on the current versions of Xamarin Forms
[Xamarin Forms timepicker 24hour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30187742/xamarin-forms-timepicker-24hour)
this one looks like it works but doesn't when the control is launched through code with Focus(). It also give a nullpointerexception when selecting a time.
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/21119/xamarin-forms-timepicker-with-15-minutes-intervals
doesn't seem to work at all.

Answer (score 0):

There is also another answer for this that i used in my project:

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/21119/xamarin-forms-timepicker-with-15-minutes-intervals

Hope this helps.